# How sessions are used in connection pool maintained in mysql

Tags: mysql

After surfing a bit about connection vs session.
Connection is the physical thing existing between client and server. Whereas session comes to picture after physical connectivity. 
I am actually usually connection pool(user with all privileges) to connect to mysql server.

I am not creating N users in mysql rather connecting to common user (root) to fetch all data. Is it possible to set some user specific information(session related) along with each connections initialised in a pool.

Comment: Each connection from the server running your application corresponds to a PROCESS in the Mysql server. To understand what you mean by session, we need to know the language and database api used in you app server. Java/JDBC? php/mysqli? C#/connector.net? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: MySQL knows nothing about pools and sessions - this is not its entities and scope of interest. From MySQL side each connection is separate and independent connection non-relative to all another connections.

Comment: The reference you quote is from "Expert ORACLE JDBC Programming". This is not MySQL (which has no "pools"). Please re-word your question so that it is clearer what you want to ask.

Comment: I am using java/jdbc..Connection will be established with some root user. Is it possible to have any app server user information passed to mysql ?

Comment: Connecting as root sounds like a security breach just waiting to happen.